# How can i stop NGINX from clearing environment variables

Tags: nginx, environment-variables

By default NGINX clears all environment variables and I am currently using an NGINX module that executes a binary, the executed binary relies on a large number of env variables that are set on the system by default but NGINX clears them, I know about the `env` directive in NGINX by I can't list and don't know all the environment variables that the executable relies on.

Comment: Cannot be done without modifying source of nginx and creating a custom build

Comment: Apparently that's the case I guess i'll close this one